# Change remote desktop keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, shortcut, remote-desktop

I program using the remote desktop feature of Windows. In visual studio, the shortcut to stop debugging by default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>.

The problem is that this is the same shortcut to change the full screen mode of the remote desktop screen.

Each time I hit the shortcut while programming, my brain reminds me that for the millionth time: "Ahhhhhhh, this shortcut doesn't work when I'm in remote connection".

I know that I can change the shortcut in visual studio but is there any possibility to change the shortcut of the remote desktop instead of changing it in visual studio?

I'm an old programmer with old habits... :(

Thank you.

Comment: I finally just changed my shortcut to "Ctrl+Shift+Break". This shortcut is not used by any other feature and I'm very happy of that. Thank you to my fingers which had the idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the Remote Desktop Connection dialog, Local Resources -> Keyboard -> On the remote computer

Maybe changing this options can help you (can't try it myself at the moment).

Anyway I think that there is no easy method for changing that key mappings, maybe through registry.

Answer (score 0):

Try my RDP management utility for windows, I also program using visual studio on a remote machine, and never meet this problem.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> would not toggle fullscreen while other shutcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> still works.

btw, this tabbed remote management app helpes you launching remote sessions very convenient and fast. hope you can enjoy it and help to improve it. Any of your advice or report is priceless .

https://github.com/VShawn/PRemoteM